# Can Int's default size be changed?

Tags: ios, swift, int, int64, int32

On 64-bit platforms, `Int` is the same size as `Int64`, and on 32-bit platforms, `Int` is the same size as `Int32`.

Can this behavior be changed, i.e. can `Int`'s size be forced to be `Int32` on 64-bit platforms?

Comment: Yes you can, use Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64

Answer (score 5):

The idea behind `Int` is that it reflects the [native size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Si) (32-bit on 32-bit system and 64-bit on 64-bit system).

If you really want a 32-bit int no matter what platform you're on then you use `Int32`.
If you really want a 64-bit int no matter what platform you're on then you use `Int64`.

To solve your problem be explicit and just use `Int32` instead of `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple data types available in *Swift* to define an *integer*

```
 - Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64 

 - UInt, UInt8, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64
```

You can use any of the above as per your requirement independent of whether you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit platform.